# Java : Parsing a String & Checking for "@"

Tags: java

How can i use Pattern.compile to check whether a string contains "@". Something like this->>

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\.-]*@[\\.\\w-]*$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    return matcher.matches();
```

Comment: Does that not work? (I'd change the `*` to `+`, as there *must* be something on either side of the `@`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *only* need to check whether it contains an @, then just a regex of "@" should work:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
return matcher.find();
```

(Note that `matches` will see whether the *whole* input matches the pattern, whereas `find` will just see whether the pattern is *present* within the input, which is what you need here.)

Any reason not to just use `x.indexOf('@') != -1` or `x.contains("@")` though?

Comment: No particular reason. Can you let me know to use String.indexof for the same?

Comment: @SpunkerBaba: just `return string.indexOf('@') != -1;` or `return string.contains("@");`

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary to use a Pattern?

```
return string.contains("@");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use a pattern another solution is :

```
return string.matches("^[\\w\\.-]*@[\\.\\w-]*$");
```